# Expanding to show fields - Visual Studio C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, listview, expandablelistview, windows-forms-designer

I will have a yes and no radio button, and if the user selects Yes, It will expand and show more fields, if no then it wouldn't. Now, I was thinking of having two different panels, the second one would be hidden, and when the user selects 'Yes', I can set it to visible and it will show on the screen. But the problem with this is it would have a huge gap where the hidden panel is positioned.

Is there another way of doing this?

P.S I am working on visual studio 2010 C# windows form.

Comment: @HansPassant not a good idea, cant control the position of components

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use the panel and set the visibility to true when called upon and false when not required.